# SWT Java - Putting composite with image background on a shell with image background

Tags: java, swt

I am writing a graphical application using SWT. Firstly I created a shell with image background (shell.setBackgroundImage(image)) then I put a composite with another background image, so that I could use it(composite) to place labels inside it. The problem is that I cannot get rid of the gray border around composite. Is it possible to do at all or perhaps there are others way to do that?

Here is the code:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class Test {

    protected static int gap = 20;

    public static void main (String[] args) {

       Display display = new Display();
       Shell shell = new Shell(display);   
       Image bg_Image = new Image(display, "bg_full.png"); 
       shell.setBackgroundImage(bg_Image);
       shell.setBackgroundMode(SWT.INHERIT_FORCE);  
       shell.setFullScreen(true);

       Image bg = new Image(display, "bg.png");
       Image border = new Image(display, "bg_info.png");
       Image b1 = new Image(display, "button_total_active.png");
       Image b2 = new Image(display, "button_terminal.png");
       Image b3 = new Image(display, "button_operator.png");
       Image b4 = new Image(display, "button_contract.png");

       Composite composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
       composite.setBackgroundImage(bg);
       composite.setBackgroundMode(SWT.INHERIT_FORCE);
       composite.setBounds(80, 220, bg.getBounds().width, bg.getBounds().height);

       Label label1 = new Label(composite, SWT.NONE);
       label1.setImage(b1);
       label1.setBounds(gap, gap, b1.getBounds().width, b1.getBounds().height);

       Label label2 = new Label(composite, SWT.NONE);
       label2.setImage(b2);
       label2.setBounds(gap, gap*2+b1.getBounds().height, b2.getBounds().width, b2.getBounds().height);

       Label label3 = new Label(composite, SWT.NONE);
       label3.setImage(b3);
       label3.setBounds(gap, gap*3+b1.getBounds().height*2, b3.getBounds().width, b3.getBounds().height);

       Label label4 = new Label(composite, SWT.NONE);
       label4.setImage(b4);
       label4.setBounds(gap, gap*4+b1.getBounds().height*3, b4.getBounds().width, b4.getBounds().height);

       Label label5 = new Label(composite, SWT.NONE);
       label5.setImage(border);
       label5.setBounds(gap*2+b1.getBounds().width, gap, border.getBounds().width, border.getBounds().height);

       shell.open();
       while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
           if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();      
       }
       display.dispose();

   }
}
```

Here is a [sample image](http://file.karelia.ru/qgt8v7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not gray borders (you removed them by SWT.INHERIT_FORCE), these are transparent corners of the image that are not transparent because there is a composite behind them. As far as I know you cannot remove the corners of the image using it as a background of a Composite. If these corners are transparent (and not white), you can draw this image on the Shell (without creating any Composite) using GC as shown [here](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-images/graphics-resources.html).
When placing transparent images, put them on the object you expect to see behind. Hope I helped u. :)

Comment: Gene Marin thanks for answering my question, yes I know that these borders are transparent (maybe I didn't make that clear) and I also familiar with drawing using GC) The problem is that I don't how to handle this obstacle: I create shell(with image background), then I can draw Image on it, then I need to put more labels(with images) above this Image, but the transparent parts of these images inherit shell's background, I want to overcome this, maybe you have any ideas? Hope this link(http://file.karelia.ru/5rrvrv/) will clarify my question. Thanks in advance

Comment: Never mind I used Swing for handling this obstacle it works perfect. Thanks anyway